# Здравствуйте помогите написать программу на C#

Tags: c#, c, математика, ряды

Написать программу, которая введет значение переменной n, и сосчитает сумму ряда :

```
1/2 + 1/(2*3) + 1/(3*4) + ..... + 1/(n*(n+1))
```

[image: С#]

Answer (score 2):

Вообще-то

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

так что вся программа сводится к

```
sum = 1 - 1./(n+1)
```

Хотя, думаю, от вас хотят совсем другое, так что данный ответ вряд ли является выполнением ДЗ за вас :)